# botbuilder-integration-aiohttp error: Failed building wheel for aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp, python-wheel

When installing the botbuilder-integration-aiohttp I keep getting the following error. I am using following version of python 3.12.2 and aiohttp 3.9.3. I use the Python Botbuilderframework SDK for MS Teams Bots.

```
╰─ pip install botbuilder-integration-aiohttp                                                                                                                                  ─╯
...
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [188 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/worker.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/multipart.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_response.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tracing.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_middlewares.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_app.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/streams.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/log.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_request.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_websocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_proto.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/locks.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_server.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/base_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_reqrep.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_log.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/resolver.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/formdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload_streamer.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_routedef.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/connector.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/typedefs.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/hdrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/cookiejar.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/pytest_plugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/abc.py -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp/*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp/_cparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_headers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      creating build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_cparser.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_find_header.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyi.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_websocket.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/hdrs.py.hash -> build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk -I/Users/timkrause/code/projects/msTeamsBots/Mecho/venv/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/aiohttp/_websocket.o
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1475:17: warning: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        if (unlikely(!Py_OptimizeFlag)) {
                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/pydebug.h:13:1: note: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) PyAPI_DATA(int) Py_OptimizeFlag;
      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2680:27: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          return likely(dict) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict) : 0;
                                ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2692:36: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          return (dictptr && *dictptr) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(*dictptr) : 0;
                                         ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2696:56: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          if (unlikely(!dict) || unlikely(tp_dict_version != __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)))
                                                             ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
              ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1125:16: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
          if (likely(__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT) == __pyx_dict_version)) {\
                     ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
              ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1129:30: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
              __pyx_dict_version = __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT);\
                                   ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3042:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3097:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3238:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3293:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3744:47: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
          const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)b)->ob_digit;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      6 warnings and 5 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I just tried reinstalling it and used pyenv with python 3.10.0. All packages I use are up to date.

Comment: Despite what you've listed in the question, this library doesn't appear to be using aiohttp 3.9.3 yet. You must be trying to install 3.8 which doesn't support Python 3.12. The dependency was bumped (I don't know why they are pinning it...) last month, which is after the latest release: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blame/main/libraries/botbuilder-integration-aiohttp/setup.py#L13